# Extract the county (or village) level data of forest cover change from Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, county

I am currently working with the Hansen data (Global Forest Change) in Earth Engine. And I would like to extract the county (or village) level data of forest cover change in China from Google earth engine.

The problems is that I'm not sure if I can extract the county (or village) level data by using google earth engine, also I don't know what I need for specifying the boundaries if I can extract the county level data. I've tried to read most of the GUIDES and use the Featurecollection to specify but couldn't make it.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify - by extract, do you mean that you'd like to export this data for use outside of Google Earth Engine?  Or are you trying to access the data in this boundary / bounding box for use within GEE?